# Why was there a POI mismatch in Episode S01E05?

Tags: plot-explanation, person-of-interest

In *Person of Interest* Episode E01E05, Reese and Finch did observe judge Sam Gates at the beginning. However, the Person of Interest was his son, whose name is the same.

**How could that happen?** As we know, the machine only gives a social security number and they should be different even if people have the same name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The machine didn't get it wrong**. The POI *was* the judge. Reese does *think* it was wrong at first:

> Reese: Finch, what's the son's name again?
>   Finch: Samuel Gates Junior. Why?
>   Reese: I think we've been following the wrong Sam Gates.

Reese says it because the son is then kidnapped. But the machine identified Sam the father because **he's the victim of a bigger conspiracy** involving a crime gang and money laundering. This is also explained in the episode:

> Finch: **The machine identifies malice and an intent to harm. We need to determine which threat it saw, which one is real.** [...] The machine did not send us the wrong number. If it says that judge Gates is in danger, then he is. [...] The kidnapping must connect. It could be the first step in a larger plot.

And he's right. The son's kidnapping is supposed to sway the judge to rig a trial, so he's a potential victim of extortion and eventually murder, as Finch states near the end:

> Finch: The machine sent us his number because they were planning to kill him all along. Him and his son.

Comment: If they planed to kill both of them, Judge and his son, then why The Machine didn't give his son's social number as well? :)